# Node 6.9 Angular 7 compatibility

Tags: node.js, angular

I have node 6.9 installed along with it`s packages, now when I am installing angular7 it asks me to upgrade it, but I get error when I run my node server in 6.9 (I cannot change the version due to some constraint). Any alternative?

Comment: You need Node in Angular only to develop it, unless you use SSR. You can use multiple Node versions if needed, depending on your setups and needs. With `nvm` or else.

Answer (score 0):

Use nave by installing `npm i -g nave` and you can create any node version environment you want.

`nave use X.X.X` will automatically build your new nodejs environment. Then you can create a new angular project from this terminal.